# JavaScript - Output variables to console prevent scrolling

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, console.log

I have a set of variables I am trying to monitor in the Chrome Devtools Console. It is a fairly extensive list of 25 and I am currently outputting them like this...

```
console.log(variable1);
console.log(variable2);
console.log(variable3);
console.log(variable4);
console.log(variable5);
console.log(variable6);
```

This is working but is difficult to debug as they are constantly scrolling down the list. Is there a better way to monitor variables in one place?

Alternatively could I set the variables to rewrite the line instead of add?

Comment: Try `console.log(variable1, variable2)`;

Comment: Can you cache all variables in an Array, and then `console.dir(variableArray)`? Unfortunately we can’t give you any particular insight without seeing enough of your code to see where your variables come from, can you post a sample of your representative code?

Comment: Try switching to [live expressions](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/08/devtools#watch) instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you have var1, var2, var3......

You can:

```
console.log(var1, var2, var3, ...);
```

If you're using Chrome DevTools, you can even:

```
console.table({var1, var2, var3, ... });
```

[image]

Comment: Table is good, thank you!  Much easier to see what is going on

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use something like this:

```
console.log({ variable1, variable2, variable3, variable4, ... })
```

Answer (score 1):

You could pass multiple paramaters comma separated for [console.log](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log):

```js
let variable1 = "a",
  variable2 = "b";
console.log(variable1, variable2);
```